# How to hyperlink the fetched data?

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to php, mysql. currently i'm building a website. with the search query the data is displayed  well. (in this case the search query is 'name %like%'). now i want to open another page that will display the profile of any one of the name displayed (when clicked) in the previous query. how to acheive this?

Answer (score 1):

you'll have to select, for example, user_id when searching.

and then, your code could look like

```
<?php
include("db.php");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT user_id, username FROM user WHERE username LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username'])."%'");
echo "<table>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)
{
    echo '<tr><td><a href="profile.php?uid='.$row['user_id'].'">'.$row['username'].'</a></td></tr>';

}
echo "</Table>";
```

Comment: thanks genesis. for the last two days ur script gave me lots of errors. finally i could make it (small problem with my table).

Comment: @afa: I doubt it is my fault ;)